# task.ref.getDownloadURL() throws "storage/object-not-found" error

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

When I try to upload files to the storage server, it uploads fine. But when I subscribe to the snapshot changes to get the download URL, it throws an error.

Here is my code:

```
    const fileForUpload = this.filesForUpload[0];
    this.afStorage
        .upload(
            fileForUpload.path,
            fileForUpload.file,
            fileForUpload.metadata
        )
        .snapshotChanges()
        .subscribe(task => {
            const downloadUrl = task.ref.getDownloadURL(); // throws error!
        });
```

Here's the error message:

> Firebase Storage: Object
>   'reddit/1532105412851_node_js_hexagon-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg' does
>   not exist.

Here's a screenshot if you want more details on the error message:

[image]

It says `reddit/` because I'm recreating reddit.com for practice.

When I look at my storage on firebase, I see the file uploaded fine.

Answer (score 0):

use the call back function

```
this.storage.ref(path).putString(this.image, 'data_url').then(data => {
      //data in this case contains the download ref
     console.log(data) //this will help you see the response
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems `.subscribe()` doesn't work but `.then()` does.